# Kio estas la esperanta nombro disigilo, komo aŭ mallarĝa spaceto?

Tags: numbers

En Vikiklerigeja [kurso pri internaciigo](https://beta.wikiversity.org/wiki/Internaciigo_de_komputilaj_programoj/Pli_alt-nivelaj_problemoj#Nombroj) mi ŝanĝis la rimarko pri la esperanta nombrnotacio, ĉar mi kredas ke la disigilo inter milaj grupoj estas mallarĝa spaceto, anstataŭ la komo origine verkita. Ĉu vi konas aŭtoritatan fonton pri tio? Mi ne trovis en la PMEG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Mallarĝa spaceto**

---

Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html#i-mnc) (ekstrakto):

> Oni povas uzi punktojn por klariga disigado de ciferoj en altaj nombroj, ekz.: *10.000.000.000* (= “dek miliardoj”), sed estas pli bone uzi (se eble) mallarĝajn spacetojn, ekz.: *10 000 000 000*. Ne uzu punkton antaŭ decimaloj en nombroj. Por tiu celo oni uzu komon.

Kaj por la komo vidu kelkajn alineojn sube (ekstrakto):

> Komo estas ankaŭ uzata antaŭ decimaloj en nombroj: *3,14* (= “tri komo unu kvar”, “tri kaj dek kvar centonoj”).

Por pli da informoj, ankaŭ vidu la sekcion pri [matematikaj esprimoj](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/matematiko.html).